# What do the "+n" values mean at the end of a method name in a stack trace?

Tags: c#, .net

When reading a stack trace like:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +2755599
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +112
   System.Convert.ToInt32(String value) +68
```

What do the +68, +112, etc. numbers mean. I'm guessing that they're offsets to something. If so, what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means:

> it’s an offset into the native instructions for the method.

Read [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/01/24/funny-numbers-in-my-stack-trace.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 15):

I believe they're offsets into the code of the method - whether IL or JIT-compiled-assembly bytes, I'm not sure...

(Basically they're taking the place of line numbers, which of course aren't available without the pdbs.)

Comment: They're byte offsets from the start of the function to the return address.

Comment: Don't know - I was disambiguating that they go to the return address. :)

Comment: By "return address" do you mean "where the next level in the stack would return to" (i.e. next statement)? Otherwise it sounds like you mean a return statement within the code, which would be pretty useless.

Comment: "when control is returned to the caller, this is the address from which execution will resume" (eg, the conventional meaning of return address)

Comment: I believe they are offset to machine code bytes. In a stack trace that I have the offset is +452 and the last function IL instruction is at 0x102 (unfortunately - since I'd like to be able to determine what instruction causes problems).

Comment: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/01/24/funny-numbers-in-my-stack-trace.aspx

Comment: Oh, wow. So it's the byte offset from the function start after the final translation to x86 byte code. That's... kind of dumb, but also understandable since that's what actually executes at the moment something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

it is the byte offset into native code.

With ILDASM you know why.

Comment: ILDASM won't show you the native code though - did you mean byte offset into the IL?

Answer (score 0):

Simply said, a Stack Trace is a reverse chronological listing of functions/methods in a flow, till current code. That is, up until a breakpoint is hit or an exception occurs.

On top of the stack trace listing, is the current method and its details like the Class, Assembly, filename, etc.

Following lines, list the method from where the previous method (one in the above line) was called. Going down the list, this continues to show the call stack, all the way back to the start of the program.

All these details from Stack Trace is beneficial, as it lists the origin of a method call and the intermediate methods/functions till it reached the current line of code. This is very much helpful because, if there are multiple ways to access the current method, Stack Track lists the exact flow followed.