# What means digits in Stack Trace

Tags: asp.net, .net, stack-trace

Exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305244/what-do-the-n-values-mean-at-the-end-of-a-method-name-in-a-stack-trace).

When you get an error in .Net application we got an a Stack Trace.
For example

```
  [ADOException: cannot open connection]
  NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.OpenConnection() +153
  Hibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.GetConnection() +119
  NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.get_Connection() +42
```

What do those digits mean?

Answer (score 3):

The number indicates line of the error. If complied in release mode it refers to Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) line in that function in the dll. If compiled in debug mode it refers to actual line in your code.