# How to use +number in asp.net server error page?

Tags: asp.net-2.0

If my app throws an exception I see the server error page. The stack track shows the method where the error occurred (null reference exception for example), and a plus number, like +730. How can I backtrack that number to the line of c# code?

Edit: I don't know what "+730" represents and I don't have a reference manual for it. One thing I can tell you is that this is not a line in a C# file.

Answer (score 1):

"it’s an offset into the native instructions for the method" - see http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/01/25/funny-numbers-in-my-stack-trace.aspx

Answer (score 1):

They're offset to machine code bytes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305244/what-do-the-n-values-mean-at-the-end-of-a-method-name-in-a-stack-trace).

If you add the pdb files you might get the .NET code line number.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Visual Studio you can press Ctrl+G and enter the line number you want on the page that exception occurs
also you can watch the Stack Trace using Debug > Window > Stack trace
hope it helps

Comment: It's not a line number in the source code! It might be a line in CIL but I have no quick tool to bring that up. I would not post here if I could find any documentation.