# Go to character in Visual Studio 2015 instead of go to line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I apologize in advance, this feels like a really dumb question but I am genuinely stuck.

I get the following error:

[image]

I've circled in blue my main question. Is this the character position of the error?  And if so, how do I jump to it in my c# code in visual studio?

Comment: Try doing a debug build to test for this error so you'll get line numbers as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305244/what-do-the-n-values-mean-at-the-end-of-a-method-name-in-a-stack-trace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content of your blue circle is a byte offset into the native code.

---

#### How to find the Error in the Source

*Personally i have to say debugging at the assembly level doesn't make any sense and i couldn't find a simple way for achieve this.*

But you could generate a `*.pdb` file next to your build. Then the runtime will print you **a line number** close to where the exception occurred.

Enable this in Visual Studio under:

- Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Output -> and set Debug Info to `PDB-only` or `Full`.

[image: Advanced Build Settings Window]

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for OP on how to actually find the line in the source where the error occurs?

Comment: @poke still googling for a simple way to this with ILDASM.

Comment: Best solution is to test on a debug build.

Comment: @Smartis I was hoping you would expand your answer which at the moment is very short and while correct, just barely helpful.

Comment: @poke It tried to point out How to get the Line Number back in the exception. But i'm no assembly level geek. Sorry :(

Comment: Much better answer now though, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, this is very helpful!